# some videos from iCloud are present in Photos but missing from iMovie

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, video, imovie

I have taken a bunch of videos on my iPhone, and I have iCloud so they sync automatically to Photos.  All the videos from my phone show up in Photos.

I'd like to make a movie with them, using iMovie.

In iMovie I select the Libraries -> Photos option, and my iCloud videos show up in there.  Except not all of them - there is only a subset of what's visible in Photos.

The missing ones and the present ones are the same format, same size, taken on the same phone just minutes apart.

You can see in the screenshot the corresponding images (purple and yellow), and the missing ones (red).

The images are clearly present in iCloud since that's how they are visible in Photos.

I've tried restarting iMovie, to no avail.

[image]